# How to control system volume with C++/QML?

Tags: application-development, c++, qml

Helo,

I want to develop an app.

It should control the system volume by day time.

I have two questions:

1. How to change system volume in C++/QML?
2. How can I run my app as a service that will automatically change the system volume by day time?

Comment: The app has to run on ubuntu phone!